# Confused about the definition of partial derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, definition, partial-derivative

If we take partial derivative of $x+x'$ with respect to $x$, do we get $1$?

This is rather a simple question but I cannot answer this with the definition of partial derivative in the wikipedia...

Comment: what do you mean with " $x'$ "?

Comment: @gimusi derivative of $x$

Comment: then x'=1 and thus $x+x'=x+1$

Comment: Partial derivative is used when there are more than one variables , keeping one varaint ... others are kept constant ... Here , only $x$ is the variable ... So the maths succumbs to a normal differentiation

Comment: You say $x'$ is the derivative of $x$, but is this with respect to $x$ as well? Otherwise $x'$ is not $1$, it's unknown.

Comment: @Mhr Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial derivative is exactly as the ordinary derivative for function of one variable keeping the Others variable constant and deriving by the variable considered.

Then in your case since

$$x+x'=x+1\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+1)=1$$